Proof of a martingale condition regarding martingale transform
I tried to work on my previous question regarding a Converse of a martingale transform theorem, and was told by a stochastics PhD student at my university that indeed if an integrable, adapted process $X$ in $\mathbb{R},$ and a predictable and bounded $C$ yield
$$E[(C\bullet X)_n]=0$$
then $X$ must be a martingale.
Where the transform is defined as $(C\bullet X)_n\stackrel{\text{def.}}{=}\sum_{k=1}^{n} C_k(X_k-X_{k-1})$
Yet she couldn't offer me a proof of it at that time. I myself see no way to prove it. I would appreciate any help or a reference to where I could find a proof.

$$
\begin{align}
C_n(\mathbb E[X_n\vert\mathcal F_{n-1}]-X_{n-1})&=\mathbb E[C_n(X_n-X_{n-1})\vert\mathcal F_{n-1}]\\
&=\mathbb E[(C\bullet X)_n-(C\bullet X)_{n-1}\vert\mathcal F_{n-1}]\\
&=0.
\end{align}
$$
So if $C$ almost surely never takes the value $0$ then $\mathbb E[X_n\vert\mathcal F_{n-1}]=X_{n-1}$ and $X$ is indeed a martingale.
If $C$ can be zero then $X$ need not be a martingale. The obvious counter-example is $C=0$ which yields $C\bullet X=0$ whatever $X$ is.

could you please explain why are we calculating $C_n(\mathbb E[X_n\vert\mathcal{F}{n-1}]-X{n-1})$ in the first place nad what is the meaning of it? I also am not sure why we are allowed to take the expectation in front and move the $X_{n-1}$ inside the left side of the conditional expectation

We want to show that $\mathbb E[X_n\vert\mathcal F_{n-1}]=X_{n-1}$, which can be rewritten $\mathbb E[X_n-X_{n-1}\vert\mathcal F_{n-1}]=0$. So we are interested in the behaviour of $X_n-X_{n-1}$. But with $C\bullet X$ we have information on $C_n(X_n-X_{n-1})$. So the multiplication by $C_n$ is natural to make use of the initial assumption.
$C_n$ and $X_{n-1}$ are both $\mathcal F_{n-1}$-measurable, which is why they can go in and out of the conditional expectation given $\mathcal F_{n-1}$.
